# Error when trying to create a new Profile

Tags: wordpress, profile, forms, civiprofile

I am trying to create a new CiviCRM Profile for a new submission form.
I had no problem doing this before.
But I tried to copy one Profile to create the new one.
And now I get this error/warning (see photo) and I am wondering how I caused this and how it can be fixed.  Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Can you please describe the problem in more detail? When do you see the error? When clicking the "Copy Profile" button, or on every page?
What version of CiviCRM are you using?

Comment: I'm using CiviCRM Version 5.67.1

Comment: I get the error on every Profile after I try to save any edits.

Comment: I tested multiple Profiles, and they all have the same error now.  I am wondering if this was caused by the copy Profile feature.  I am hoping there's a fix for this, because I can't edit any of my Profiles.

Comment: I'm going to test deleting and reloading a fresh version of CiviCRM in my dev site to see if it's fixed.

Comment: I copied over my live site to a dev site, and it's the same error.  I'm thinking of scrapping CiviCRM all together !

Comment: Can you enable the debug & backtrace settings on your dev site. That should give you a more complete error msg you can share here.

Comment: I installed my back up version of my website and solved my problem.  The profiles now work again, but I lost some of my updates. This just shows how important it is to back up sites regularly.  Does anyone have any recommendations for site back ups ?